# How to prevent tabs from changing on their own?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I have a set of tabs that are having an issue on mobile. When the window is scrolled the selected tab closes itself and goes back to the default tab (the one shown on page load).  How can I prevent this from happening, so that when a user selects a tab it stays open until they choose another one?

Here is my code:

```js
function openTab(evn, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-content");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-link");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evn.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

 document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <button class="tab-link" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab-content')" id="defaultOpen">
    Tab Title #1
  </button>
  <button class="tab-link" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab-content-two')">
    Tab Title #2
  </button>
  <button class="tab-link" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab-content-three')">
    Tab Title #3
  </button>
</div>

<div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
    Content for first tab.
</div>

<div id="tab-content-two" class="tab-content">
    Content for second tab.
</div>

<div id="tab-content-three" class="tab-content">
    Content for third tab.
</div>
```

Comment: Is there really an `openTab2` function? `<button class="tab-link" onclick="openTab2(event, 'tab-content-three')">`

Comment: @Rob Moll - no sorry, I modified the code from the production site, for simplicity on SO, I will fix now

Comment: Are you "checking on mobile" by resizing the browser? Maybe you have some responsive javascript or CSS like media queries that reset the display or visibility properties of the elements

Comment: @Ivan86 - I am checking on a real phone.  When I check with the mobile view in Chome Inspect tools, I don't have the issue

Comment: @rob moll - I have approved your minor format adjustment, any luck on a solution to the question?

Comment: @lisrael I didn't make any format adjustments. I added the code snippet so that others can see your code in action. As you stated, it appears to work fine in the browser using dev tools. No luck on a solution that so far only appears on your test phone when the window is scrolled.

Comment: @Rob Moll - Thanks for adding that code snippet so it runs. It's not just my phone, but also the client's and I checked android an iOS, perplexing